# subfigure: Missing number, treated as zero and Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

Tags: subfloats

i use below code to view 2 images A & B:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{4cm}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When i use above code, no error but when i insert this code to my big main.tex file, get 2 errors:
Missing number, treated as zero and 
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

And number 0.5 of {0.5\linewidth} displayed with image.

How can i remove number 0.5?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but how should we know what your big main file is doing to break the code? Make a copy of your main file add only the body of your example and then start to remove packages to find the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue if I change `\usepackage{subcaption}` into `\usepackage{subfigure}` (or use both, with `subfigure` prior to `subcaption`).

Either use `subfigure` (but bear in mind it is obsolete) or `subcaption`, not both.

If you *have* to use a template that forces `subfigure`, then use the proper syntax that you find in its manual.

Answer (score 2):

just replace `{0.5\linewidth}` with `{}`, coming after `begin{subfigure}` and specify width of the figure in `\includegraphics` only

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please elaborate more your answer posting a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304)?

Comment: As OP noted in his question, showed MWE works, but if (s)he move figure code to unknown main document, not anymore. However,  @egreg answer address possible causes of OP problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.